# compound shard key chunks boundaries

Tags: mongodb

How are compound shard key used to generate new chunks? I mean, if I have a shard key like

{key1 : 1, key2 : 1}

and the collection is being populated as we go, how does MongoDB create the new chunks boundaries given that there are two keys? I can see them in the config server BUT I can not read them. they look like

[min key1,min key2] ---> [max key1, max key2]

and many often, **min key 2**> **max key 2**. How does that make sense?

In other words, how are the chunks min and max being set on new chunks given the shard key is compound?

key 1 is of type string and key 2 is of type int

I would appreciate it if you could explain it by an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boundary is always from positive to negative infinity. As you insert it will break that initial chunk into smaller ones.

[Here is a thread which should answer your question.](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/ca895f73a07724bf)

Comment: Sorry, I am still not following. Why the second key goes up and down?

Comment: Don't think of them as separate keys... they are single (combined) shard key. Think of them as the concatenation of the two values.

Comment: oh, I see, how do mongodb define the range boundaries for a combined key which is composed of an string and an int?